# When starting Microsoft Teams there is always one question

Tags: microsoft, microsoft-teams

When starting Microsoft Teams there is always one question:

Recruitment condition?

Change the Snap "Teams for Linux", "Default URL Scheme Handler" subproperty "msteams" to "Teams for Linux_teams for Linux.desktop"?

This dialog is closed after 5 minutes of Inactivated.

I will have this question awake.

Comment: Can you rephrase and you should choose yes yes